# postgis query to find neighbour

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

```
SELECT * 
FROM offer 
ORDER BY profile.location <-> "offer.profile.location"
```

I have 2 tables: one is `offer` and another one is `profile`. `offer` is provided by user in the profile, so for a user in `profile` how to query to find nearest `offer` using postgis postgresql?

Comment: provide table fields?

Comment: for both tables

Comment: class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326,geography=True,)

Comment: class GiveOffer(models.Model):
    giver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    offer_started_date = models.DateTimeField()
    offer_end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    note_on_offer = models.TextField()
    properties = JSONField()

Comment: sorry for mistakes i updated my question

Comment: is there anything wrong with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some thing like this. In this it is supposed that SRID is 4326, locations must be within 5000 meters of each other and the result of offer is ordered by distance.

```
 SELECT offer.* FROM offer, profile
    WHERE ST_DWithin(offer.location, profile.location, 5000)
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(offer.location, profile.location);
```

Comment: how to use for a user if ernest is a user name means  how to mention?
 like profile.ernest.location....

Comment: offer has giver whose location is refered in profile

Comment: you can just and another condition after WHERE . like WHERE profile.user =  "ernest"

Comment: SELECT offer.* FROM offer, profile
    WHERE ST_DWithin(offer.location, profile.ernest.location, 5000)
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(offer.location, profile.ernest.location);  like this or some thing

Comment: SELECT offer.* FROM offer, profile WHERE ST_DWithin(offer.location, profile.location, 5000) ORDER BY ST_Distance(offer.location, profile.location) AND  profile.user = "ernest"

Comment: it shows that ERROR:  column offer.location does not exist

Comment: I just wrote the psoudo query. As I exactly do not know your schema and data types. from "location" I meant the column that has the geometry

Comment: tq for reply i am goin to over write  my models